# Problem with Python threading and semaphores

Tags: python, concurrency

I have four processes (function0, function1, function2 and function3) and I want to print the message "hello world world from from python" 1000 times. My problem is that the program only prints "hello world world from" and gets stuck there.

Below is my code:

```
import threading

sem0= threading.Semaphore(1)
sem1 = threading.Semaphore(0)
sem2 = threading.Semaphore(0)
sem3 = threading.Semaphore(0)

def function0():
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        sem0.acquire()
        print("hello", end=" ")
        sem1.release()
        sem1.release()

def function1():
    for i in range(0, 2000):
        sem1.acquire()
        print("world", end=" ")
        if i % 2 != 0:
            sem2.release()

def function2():
    for i in range(0, 2000):
        sem2.acquire()
        print("from", end=" ")
        if i % 2 != 0:
            sem3.release()

def function3():
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        sem3.acquire()
        print("python\n")
        sem0.release()

thread0 = threading.Thread(target=function0)
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=function1)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=function2)
thread3 = threading.Thread(target=function3)

threads = []

threads.append(thread0)
threads.append(thread1)
threads.append(thread2)
threads.append(thread3)

for t in threads:
    t.start()
```

[here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cORqb.png)

Answer (score 0):

When I run it, I get no output. Anyway:

You are getting stuck because you are attempting to do too many semaphore acquires on a semaphore. If a semaphore is initialized with a value of 1, you can only do one `acquire`; a second one will block until a `release` is done on it.

The following code, for example, does what you would expect (I modified it to print only 10 times and I removed an extra newline from the `print` statement):

```
import threading

sem0 = threading.Semaphore(1)
sem1 = threading.Semaphore(0)
sem2 = threading.Semaphore(0)
sem3 = threading.Semaphore(0)

def function0():
    for _ in range(10):
        sem0.acquire()
        print("hello", end=" ")
        sem1.release()

def function1():
    for _ in range(10):
        sem1.acquire()
        print("world", end=" ")
        sem2.release()
        sem2.release()

def function2():
    for _ in range(10):
        sem2.acquire()
        print("from", end=" ")
        sem2.acquire()
        print("from", end=" ")
        sem3.release()

def function3():
    for _ in range(10):
        sem3.acquire()
        print("python")
        sem0.release()

thread0 = threading.Thread(target=function0)
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=function1)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=function2)
thread3 = threading.Thread(target=function3)

threads = []

threads.append(thread0)
threads.append(thread1)
threads.append(thread2)
threads.append(thread3)

for t in threads:
    t.start()
```

Prints:

```
hello world from from python
hello world from from python
hello world from from python
hello world from from python
hello world from from python
hello world from from python
hello world from from python
hello world from from python
hello world from from python
hello world from from python
```

[Python Demo](https://ideone.com/TtTOIx)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but I want to print this "hello world world from from python" each time. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: And I thought `from from` was a typographical error. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @user10802507 the idea about semaphore is to prevent more than certain number of workers from obtaing the same resource. Actually if there are several workers trying to access one resource, you can never be sure which of wirkes get the resouce first. To make what you want you should use either Events + Conditions from multithreading module or coroutines from asyncio.

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev Excellent point. Although a semaphore can be used with an initial count of 0 to emulate an event with a `release` serving to show the event completion *provided` that there is only one party interested in the completion of that event*, as is the case here. As a general event mechanism for which multiple parties may be subscribing to the completion, it's really not the way to go.